# Vuforia cylindrical image target ratio question

Tags: image, target, vuforia, cylindrical

I'm going crazy with cylindrical image target.

I read the Vuforia doc about how to calculate ratio but I need to have a sample made with numbers...

Then, for example, I have a bottle coke, I enter Top = 6.5 Bottom 6.5 and Height 11.
My image is 529 x 530.

In the doc I read

W = PiGreco bottom
H = sL

so, W = PiGreco 529 = 168 and H = 530

It's right? But rescaling the image Vuforia still says the ratio is not right.

Please, someone can help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The aspect ratio of your image has to match what is expected based on the target Physical dimensions. In the coke case the image ratio

W/H = PI * 6.5 / 11.0 = 1.85

for example if the image has H = 530 pixels, then

W = 1.85 * H = 1.85 * 530 = 980